# Matlab to Merge a n number of matrix (same dimensions)

Tags: matrix, merge, logic

I look to merge a n number of matrix (nm) with same number of rows, same number of columns (nc), to get a global matrix in this order

Column (x, y) : column number x in the matrix y

Column (1,1) Column (1,2) Column(1,3) to Column (1, nc), Column (2,1) Column (2,2) Column(2,3) to Column (2, nc), to Column (nc,nm)

M1 =

```
1 3
2 4
```

M2 =

```
5 7
6 8
```

... To ....
Mn =

```
X Z
Y W
```

Formed matrix =

```
1 5 ... To X 3 7 ... To Z
2 6 ... To Y 4 8 ... To W
```

I have tried an simple example

```
a = [1 1; 1 1]; aT = a';
b = [2 2; 2 2]; bT = b';
c = [3 3; 3 3]; cT = c';
d = reshape([aT(:) bT(:) cT(:)]',3*size(aT,1), [])'
```

Comment: Please let us know what you have tried already, what hasn't worked, any any other relevant information!

Comment: I tried on statics a = [1 1; 1 1];b = [2 2; 2 2]; c = [3 3; 3 3]; aT = a'; bT = b'; cT = c'; d = reshape([aT(:) bT(:) cT(:)]',3*size(aT,1), [])'

Comment: Well include your code and errors, and maybe someone will answer your question!

Comment: Please edit your post and include your code there (edit button is under your tags) under your question